# SASS: Style only first level of multi level menu?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to learn SASS and I would like to style the first level of my multi level menu using sass. Let's say this is the markup:

```
ul.menu
  li.menu-item
    ul.sub-menu
      li.menu-item
```

In CSS, I can target the first level with

```
ul.menu > menu-item
```

But I can't make ">" work on SASS. Is there another way to do this?

Edit:

Forgot to add that I'm using the & so Im trying it with this markup:

```
.menu{
  > &-item{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try this **.menu {  & > .menu-item { }  }** ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif just did. The styles disappear. My styles are still inside the { } so they did not disappear because I used your exact line.

Comment: sorry i forget to say without spaces { &>.menu-item { } }

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the &. Just `.menu { > .menu-item {` works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To generate this css

```
.menu > .menu-item {
  color: red;
}
```

your sass should look like

```
.menu {
  & > &-item {
    color: red;
  }
}
```